# Rubular versus javascript regexp capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex, rubular

Noticed a difference between what Rubular.com and Javascript regexes:

```
'catdogdogcatdog'.match(/cat(dog)/g);  // JS returns ['catdog', 'catdog']
```

I expected to capture 'dog' twice but instead I get 'catdog' twice.

Rubular captures 'dog' twice as expected: http://rubular.com/r/o7NkBnNs63

What is going on here exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Rubular also matches `catdog` twice. It *also*  shows you the contents of the capturing group, which captured `dog` twice.

[image: screen shot from rubular]

You want something like this:

```
var myregexp = /cat(dog)/g;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
while (match != null) {
    dog = match[1]
    // do something, Gromit!
    match = myregexp.exec(subject);
}
```